# Retrieving Query Parameter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-decorators

While using Python and it's Flask framework I have a button link on a specific page that passes an id numeric value (using the Jinja2 templating engine):

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
              {% for employee in the_employees %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.last_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.role}}</td>
                    <td>
                      <a class="btn btn-success" role="button" href="/empdetails/{{employee.id}}">Details</a>
                      <a class="btn btn-info active" role="button" href="/scheduleinfo/{{employee.id}}" style="margin-left:5px;">Schedule</a>
                    </td>

                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Which is meant to be handled by Python's Flask decorator route that obtains that id from a list of employees:

```
employees = [{'id':1, 'name': "Jonathan", 'last_name':"Wilkinson", "email":"jwilki@zbigg.com", 'phone':"98753215646", 'role':"Owner"},
            {'id':2, 'name': 'Mary', 'last_name': 'Sue', 'email': 'jjeelasj221@zbigg.net',  'phone': "932342384758", 'role': 'Manager'},
            {'id':3,'name': "Joanna", 'last_name': "Kenderson", 'email':'kjjsdakjae@kkzbigg.com', 'phone': '9876478398478', 'role': 'Employee'}
            ]

@app.route('/empdetails/<emp_id>')
def emp_details(emp_id) -> str:
    the_id = emp_id
```

Yet, this value is ignored, despite the id value clearly displaying in the address bar. Is there a specific requirement that has to be meant before it's passed?
Or is there a library that allows to do that way easier?

Comment: `@app.route('/empdetails/<emp_id>'))` is invalid syntax, the correct decorator should be `@app.route('/empdetails/<emp_id>')`

Comment: True, I must have mistyped while copy-pasting. But the same issue remains without the round bracket.

Comment: It seems this is related to how buttons work, as whenever i pass it through the query string by itself it does not ignore the value.

Comment: Try printing `emp_id` above the `the_id` declaration. What are the results?

Comment: Also, if `employee` does not have an attribute `id`, then `{{employee.id}}` will fail silently, and `/empdetails/` will be the result.

Comment: I have updated the code in question for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either access the data values by key or create an object with the desired attributes. This answer demonstrates both.

With class to enable attribute calls:

```
class Employee:
  def __init__(self, _data):
    self.__dict__ = _data
```

Now, in the route that serves the table html:

```
@app.route('/get_employees', methods=['GET'])
def get_employees():
  employees = [{'id':1, 'name': "Jonathan", 'last_name':"Wilkinson", "email":"jwilki@zbigg.com", 'phone':"98753215646", 'role':"Owner"},
        {'id':2, 'name': 'Mary', 'last_name': 'Sue', 'email': 'jjeelasj221@zbigg.net',  'phone': "932342384758", 'role': 'Manager'},
        {'id':3,'name': "Joanna", 'last_name': "Kenderson", 'email':'kjjsdakjae@kkzbigg.com', 'phone': '9876478398478', 'role': 'Employee'}]
  return flask.render_template('table_data.html', the_employees = [Employee(i) for i in employees])
```

Or, without a class, the `html` table file becomes:

```
<td>{{employee['id']}}</td>
<td>{{employee['name']}}</td>
<td>{{employee['last_name']}}</td>
<td>{{employee['email']}}</td>
<td>{{employee['phone']}}</td>
<td>{{employee['role']}}</td>
<td>
  <a class="btn btn-success" role="button" href="/empdetails/{{employee['id']}}">Details</a>
  <a class="btn btn-info active" role="button" href="/scheduleinfo/{{employee['id']}}" style="margin-left:5px;">Schedule</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Wouldn't Flask's request have something to handle data passed outside of forms? I did get <Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/empdetails/2' [GET]> rendered (if i select employee with id: 2) whenever assigning the request object to a variable in jinja.